How to collapse all cells by default in Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code?
I am using Jupyter notebooks in Visual Studio Code, and I would like all cells (both input and output) to be collapsed by default when I open a notebook. This would allow me to have a cleaner overview of my notebook, especially when it has a large number of sections.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
I looked for a setting in settings.json and added the following line:
"jupyter.defaultCellCollapseState": true
However, this doesn’t seem to work, and the cells remain expanded by default.
I explored extensions like "Jupyter" and "Collapse Sections," but I couldn’t find an option to automatically collapse all cells at the notebook level in Visual Studio Code.
I also searched online and found JavaScript snippets for Jupyter notebooks (e.g., %%javascript), but they seem to work only in browser-based Jupyter, not in Visual Studio Code.
Does Visual Studio Code support collapsing all cells by default in Jupyter notebooks? If not, is there a workaround or script I can use to achieve this?

You can find and set shortcut keys.
CTRL+SHIFT+P to search related settings:
Collapse All Cell Outputs/Inputs.

